# When switching to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light the app name is purple when pressing toggle button and overview is shown on Samsung S7

Tags: android, material-design

I've updated the theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`. Now when pressing the toggle button, the App name color is changed from black to purple on Samsung S7.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

[image]

I've started a new Android Project on Android Studio 4.0 Beta 4.
On Genymotion emulator with Android 8.0 Samsung S7:

[image]

The color is #6A00F2 but I cannot find this is the App. I want it to be like the Contacts App. Black background, white text.

Comment: Can you share you styles.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TaskDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription) for changing the color, icon, and description of your app in the recent app list.

Kotlin:

```
val taskDescription = TaskDescription(null, null,resources.getColor(R.color.anyColor))
(this as Activity).setTaskDescription(taskDescription)
```

Java:

```
ActivityManager.TaskDescription tDesc = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, null,getResources().getColor(R.color.anyColor));
setTaskDescription(tDesc);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the background colour from purple to any other colour.You can set the `colorPrimary` attribute in the `colors.xml` to whichever colour you want. The colour of the title will be automatically generated, depending on whether you choose the primary colour as dark(white title) or light(black title).
If you want a black colour you cant set it as

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#000000</color>
```